# JSF Map binding in Repeater

Tags: java, jsf, el

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{foo}" var="keyprefix">
  <p:inputText value="#{someBean.someMap[keyprefix + 'somesuffix']}" />              
</ui:repeat>
```

I have tried using `fn:join` which doesn't work.  I tried using `.concat()` but I am not on 2.2, I'm still using 2.1.  Is there a simple way to do this I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<c:set>` to prepare the dynamic map key by just inlining the EL expression in the string literal the usual way.

```html
<c:set var="key" value="#{keyprefix}somesuffix" />
<p:inputText value="#{someBean.someMap[key]}" />
```

Comment: I actually tried that, but it doesn't work in a repeater.  Unless there is something else I'm missing?

Comment: Works for me on both Mojarra 2.1.14 and MyFaces 2.1.9. What JSF impl/version are you using?

Comment: Mojarra 2.1.2, PrimeFaces 3.2

Comment: the ui:repeater is being updated using an `<p:ajax event="change" update="panelThatContainsTheRepeater" />` if that helps

Comment: Can you describe "doesn't work" in more detail. This is after all extremely ambiguous.

Comment: User error, I wiped away all my code and redid it with the `c:set` and it worked.  Thanks for the solution :)